# HTML assign variables to element name

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to assign variable to an Element Name so that I can access the element and change the values:

```
[% FOREACH field IN ['id','type','updatedt','lastcheckdt'] %]
    <div class="row col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <dl class="details-dl">
            <label>[% field %]</label>
            <div class="details-dg">
                <dd name=[% field %] class="float-right">[% order.$field %]</dd>    
            </div>
        </dl>
    </div>
[% END %]
```

I can format the datetime for updatedt:

```
let dt_formatted = convertDateFormat("[% order.updatedt %]");
$( "[name='updatedt']" ).val(dt_formatted);
```

Unfortunate assigning [ % field %] to name does not assign any value to name:

```
<dd name=[% field %] class="float-right">[% order.$field %]</dd>
```

Comment: What's the templating language? This isn't plain HTML/JS. Also, can you rephrase your question? Do you want to complete the task using JS/jQuery or on the back end with your templating language?

Comment: @LionelRowe i thought it was `template toolkit` `perl` but it seems to have a logic error

Comment: Note that your HTML is also invalid. `label` is not a valid child of `dl`, `name` is not a valid attribute for `dd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are missing the quotes here:

```
<dd name="[% field %]" ...>
```

Comment: tried adding double quote like above but still not able to get name:

Comment: console.log('updated:'+$( "[name='updatedt']" ).val());

Comment: I think you don't need the quotes in the selector. It it should be [name=updatedt]

Comment: You can confirm that the name is right by checking the HTML using the developer tools

Comment: <dd name="[% field %]" ...> will generate  <dd name="updatedt" ...>. Now you can do document.querySelector('[name=updatedt]'); in the console to confirm that it's working.

Comment: what went wrong is I should not use .val() I should instead use .html()

Answer (score 0):

use .html() instead of .val to access the property in `<dd>`

```
$( "[name='updatedt']" ).val(dt_formatted); --> wrong
$( "[name='updatedt']" ).htmtl (dt_formatted); --> correct
```